# static resource image not showing on lightning app(component)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, static-resources

I am trying this

```
<aura:component >
<img src="resource/1484736455000/lightning_vip__Icon_one" height="30" width="30"/>
   <aura:attribute name="expense" type="Expense__c"/>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_reference.htm) about the use of static resources.

As you can see, you can call your resource like this:

```
<aura:component >
<img src="{!$Resource.Icon_one}" height="30" width="30"/>
   <aura:attribute name="expense" type="Expense__c"/>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write src="{!$Resource.Icon_one}" instead